# SSRS Variable usage inside a DATEADD function

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssms

Hi folks I wonder if anyone knew how to resolve an issue I have with my report parameter.

Im trying to create a report with the ability to look at transaction either one month ago, two months ago or 3.

This work great in SQL management studio but in SSRS it would seem I have to add parenthesis around the variable and as such this breaks the syntax.

```
WHERE TransactionCodeID IN (3,4) AND TransactionDate < DATEADD(MONTH, @Months,GETDATE())
```

Becomes this in SSRS

```
  WHERE TransactionCodeID IN (3,4) AND TransactionDate < DATEADD(MONTH, (@Months),GETDATE())
```

This throws an error. Any ideas how to overcome?  Thank you

Comment: Is your report parameter numeric? Normally parenthesis are not needed.

Comment: Yes (-1 for one month ago -2 for two month etc)

Comment: If I dont add the parenthesis then SSRS throws "you must Declare the Scalar variable"

Comment: You can use profiler to trace the exact query sent from the report to SQL server and debug it in management studio. Also check if your parameter is declared in your dataset.

Comment: If I declare the parameter in the dataset then it appears to ignore the selection from the parameter in the report (report result is 0 rows compared with 189 rows) I confirmed this by adding a SET to set the @Months = -3 then i received the 189 rows.  Seems as though the report parameter is not then passing to the dataset is a declare is in there. (I tried the profiler...i tried again with a filter...I gave up) but thank you for the help so far.

Comment: I didn't mean to declare the parameter inside the query. Check this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157187(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: I found the issue, variable type in SSRS was text... doh!!  Changed to integer and report ran perfectly.